# Why does naming my codeigniter controller "Jamie" work, but "JamiesCorner" fails?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, naming

I'm trying to make a new section on a site I'm building called "Jamie's Corner". So I duplicated a controller I already had for the "About this site..." section, renamed the file to JamiesCorner.php, and renamed the controller to "JamiesCorner". When I load the page (my_site.local/index.php/jamiescorner), I expect to see the same contents as the "About this site..." section. Instead I get the Codeigniter 404 page. I tried a lot of things but found that renaming the controller (and file) to Jamies worked. Why is this? There's nothing obviously wrong with the name "JamiesCorner". So Why is Codeigniter rejecting it?

Comment: This path "my_site.local/index.php/jamiescorner" seems wrong. Do you see your about page when you visit "my_site.local/index.php/about" (or whatever the name of your about page is)?.

Comment: Try going to "my_site.local/jamiescorner.php" instead of "my_site.local/index.php/jamiescorner"

Comment: most computer systems are case sensitive.

Comment: I haven't removed index.php from my routs just yet (that's a WHOLE 'nother post waiting to happen), so no part of the site can be accessed without gloming on index.php to the domain name :-/

Answer (score 2):

[CodeIgniter naming convention](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming) requires that only the first character in a class file and a class definition should be uppercase. Actually, that's a [rule](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names) as far as the first character is concerned. As to the rest of the name, it's not a rule but it has an impact on URLs.

Using the naming rules, the file should be **Jamies_corner.php** and the class defined like this

```
class Jamies_corner extends CI_Controller {
```

The URL to would then be `my_site.local/index.php/jamies_corner`

CodeIgniter will always force the first character to uppercase when loading a controller. But it will take the rest of the controller's name as-is. In a case-sensitive operating system (Linux of all variations) the file name MUST match exactly or the file will not be found.

In other words, using the file `JamiesCorner.php` and `class JamiesCorner` the URL would, at a minimum, need to be `my_site.local/index.php/jamiesCorner`

You could also use `.../JamiesCorner`  but without the uppercase "C" in "Corner" it will fail every time.

Comment: But this is just a convention, and for contributing to the Codigniter code base. There's nothing there that states that using CamelCasing is STRICTLY forbidden and would cause an error of any kind. After all, I use it in everything else and this controller is the only one causing an error. That didn't help but thanks anyway.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be. I'm using a CammelCased superclass for all my controllers, which in turn inherits from . If it were a rule, then all controllers should fail to load. But they don't, only this one's giving me trouble.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Manjaro. Why do you ask?

Comment: Checking to see if you're using a case-sensitive OS

Comment: Well, Manjaro's a derivative of Arch Linux, which is a UNIX type system. Honestly, do case insensitive OS' still exist?

Comment: Manjaro = case-sensitive. Got that right away thanks. Windows is case-insensitive as far as `file_exists()` is concerned.